# Springer sheaf and Deligne-Lusztig induction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, perverse-sheaves, springer-fibres

Let $G=Gl_n$ be the general linear group over the algebraic closure of a finite field $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q $ and let $F:G \to G$ be the standard Frobenius. On $G$ there is the Springer (perverse) sheaf $S$ obtained as $p_!\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$ where $p:\tilde{G}\to G$ and $\tilde{G}$ is the Grothendieck-Springer resolution $$\tilde{G}=\{\ (gB,x) \in G/B \times G \ | \ g^{-1}xg \in B \}\ .$$ Here $B$ is the standard Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices.

The perverse sheaf $S$ is endowed with a $S_n$-action: as it is semisimple, it gets decomposed as $$ S \cong \bigoplus_{\chi \in Irr(S_n)} V_{\chi} \otimes S_{\chi}$$ where the action of $ S_n$ on $S_{\chi}$ is trivial and $V_{\chi}$ is the irreducible representation indexed by $\chi$.

Notice that the $S_n$ action  induces an isomorphism $w^*:S_g \to S_g$ for any $g \in G$ (here $S_g$ is the stalk of $S$ at $g \in G$). As everything is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$, we have an isomorphism $F^*(S) \cong S$ and so for any $g \in G^F$ we have an induced isomorphism $F^*:S_g \to S_g$. Putting everything together, for any $w \in S_n$, we can define $$f_{w}:G^F \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell} $$ $$g \to Tr(w^*F^*|S_g) .$$

On the other side, for any $w \in S_n$ we can define a Deligne-Lusztig character $R^G_{T_w}(1):G^F\to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$. Namely, consider the variety $X_{B,w}=\{g \in G/B \ | \ g^{-1}F(g) \in BwB/B\}$ where $BwB/B$ is the Bruhat cell associated to $w$. This variety admits a (left) multiplication action  by $G^F$ and we get a function $$R^G_{T_w}(1): G^F \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell} $$ $$g \to Tr(g|H^{*}_c(X_{B,w},\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})) .$$

We should have an identity like $R^G_{T_w}(1)=(-1)^{sgn(w)}f_w$: how is this proves? I wasn't able t find a reference.

Comment: I don't think such an identity can be true: Take $g=1$, then $S_1=H^*(G/B))$ is the regular module of $S_n$, while the Deligne--Lusztig character value at $g=1$ is $\pm |G^F/(T_w)^F|_{p'}$...

Comment: I think the answer comes from the fact that you are taking the $Tr$ of $w^*F^*$ and not just $w^*$. Namely, (here everything is pure) you are taking into account the grading on cohomology, so the trace on the regular representation needs not to be $0$ anymore.

Comment: Oops sorry for the misreading. Then you need to restrict $g$ to be unipotent (so it is a formula for the Green function), and it is due to Lusztig et al; a comprehensive reference is Shoji - Green functions of reductive groups over a finite field - the 1986 Arcata conference vol.1

Comment: For unipotent elements I've read Lusztig proof but I don't see how to generalize to every $g$ (maybe this is supereasy sorry!). But Lusztig's proof is a little bit complicated as it uses Hecke algebras etc and also refers to Green's construction of unipotent characters: is there a simpler, maybe more direct argument which is directly in terms of Deligne-Luszitg induction?

Comment: For generalising the formula to a general $g$, one need to combine another theorem of Lusztig, namely both $f_w$ and $R_{T_w}$ satisfy a character formula in the same form using Green functions, which reduces the situation to the case of unipotent elements. For this latter formula, see (1.7.1) in Shoji's 1995 Adv paper (the first one); note that the citation number there to Lusztig's original paper is 8.5, which seems actually should be 9.5.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reference!